# Maya smoothing in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

When you press the "3" key on maya with an object selected it will smooth the object pretty much "merging" all the faces to look like one, even curving the edges. Is there an option like this in Blender I've tried Smooth Shading and Vertex smoothing and subdivisions modifiers. but nothing really gets that "single face" look. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Smooth Mesh Preview in Maya is the same as surface subdivision as far as I know. Subdivision modifier in Blender should give you very similar results. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>/<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd>/<kbd>4</kbd>/<kbd>5</kbd> shortcuts to create a new Subdivision modifier and/or set the number of subdivisions of it.

Comment: If that's not what you are after, you will need to clarify what you mean. Edit your question and post some pictures of your expectations and different results that you get.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i needed thanks so much!